# how to create a new array in Descending order of count of each duplicate value out of an old array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to arrange a new array out of an old array where there are multiple values in which there are duplicate values as well (in old array).

**The required coding should look like below**

`like so`

```
$old_array = array("1", "2" ,"3", "1", "5", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "6");

$new_array = array("3","2","1","5","6");
```

new array is arranged in descending order of the frequencies of values .eg. "3" is having count of 4, "2" is having count of 3, "1" is having count of 2 so on

Comment: If you have the same amount of occurances for an item, what is your desired order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$old_array = array("1", "2" ,"3", "1", "5", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "6");          
$values = array_count_values( $old_array );             
arsort($values);            
$result = array_keys($values);
```

**Output (for php 5.6.35):**

```
$result = 
    array(
    (int) 0 => (int) 3,
    (int) 1 => (int) 2,
    (int) 2 => (int) 1,
    (int) 3 => (int) 6,
    (int) 4 => (int) 5
)
```

Comment: Weird, I get a different output.  Which version are you using?  Post 7 versions swap the last two.  https://3v4l.org/7rqhC

Comment: rsort manual: "If two members compare as equal, their relative order in the sorted array is undefined."

Comment: I used php 5.6.35

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use [array_count_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) and then use [uksort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php) to sort the keys according to the value in the original array.

After sorting, take the array_keys.

```
$old_array = array("1", "2" ,"3", "1", "5", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "6");
$result = array_count_values($old_array);
uksort($result, function($a, $b) use ($result){
    return $result[$a] < $result[$b];
});
$new_array = array_keys($result);
print_r($new_array);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 5
    [4] => 6
)
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/RXqo8)